# Convert ADLS Gen1 to Gen2 at the time of ADF deployment

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I am trying to do an adf deployment from production instance into the development instance in order to sync up the recent changes on PROD ADF.
In the production instance we do have linked services connecting to Gen1 ADLS and Gen2 ADLS.

But in DEV we do have only Gen2 ADLS available.
Is there any way to convert/map the Linked Services with Gen1 ADLS into Gen2 at the time of deployment and vice versa.

Is there any other way to achieve the same like by replacing the linked service object in ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several tests but it seems that we can not change linked services attributes via ARM templates. You can refer this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7074a2f7-d096-431f-b7a8-c2a5e704e500/how-do-you-change-linked-services-attributes-via-arm-templates?forum=AzureDataFactory).

The linked service of Gen1 is as follows:

```
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureBlobStorage1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "connectionString": "[parameters('AzureBlobStorage1_connectionString')]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
```

The linked service of Gen2 is as follows:

```
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/AzureDataLakeStorage1')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStorage1_properties_typeProperties_url')]",
                    "accountKey": {
                        "type": "SecureString",
                        "value": "[parameters('AzureDataLakeStorage1_accountKey')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
```

Comment: Cant we replace the json object  for Gen1 with Gen2 at the time of deployment?

Comment: According to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cbe4cea-3922-47e0-9337-53c0eed663a6/rename-linked-services-via-arm-templates?forum=AzureDataFactory), I think If you are not doing CICD, you can manually update the ARM template.